# How to disable zooming of wxWebView browser?

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to disable zoom in and out of wxWebView.
From the documentation https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_web_view.html and googling I did not find any way to do this. Is there any way to disable zooming web page in wxWidgets?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that the corresponding native APIs seem to provide, so the only way of disabling it I can see is by preventing the user from zooming. E.g. you could try handling `wxEVT_MOUSEWHEEL` messages and simply ignoring them when `event.ControlDown()` returns true to prevent using Ctrl-wheel from zooming in/out.